# How can I source a base 64 encoded file in bash?

Tags: bash, source, base64

Is there a way to source a base64 encoded file in bash instead of doing this?

```
cat $DIR/data/saves/$savegame | base64 --decode > $DIR/data/saves/$savegame.decoded
. $DIR/data/saves/$savegame.decoded
rm $DIR/data/saves/$savegame.decoded > /dev/null
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If and only if you're supremely confident that the base64-encoded blob is safe:

```
$ cat test.b64
ZWNobyAidGhpcyBpcyBhIHRlc3QiCg==
$ base64 -D test.b64
echo "this is a test"
$ . <(base64 -D test.b64)
this is a test
```

Comment: . <(base64 -d test.b64) works. One difference: my base64 works with lowercase 'd' instead of uppercase 'D'

Comment: `-D` vs. `-d` is probably a distinction drawn between different versions of the utility.